# How to multiply all the columns of the dataframe in pySpark with other single column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, multiplication

I have data of all the Months from Jan to Dec for population for particular year and I have one column say "Constant" and I need to multiply that constant column value with all the columns data from Jan to Dec in spark. For Example,  I have following data :

```
        JAN FEB MAR...DEC Constant
City1   160 158 253   391   12
City2   212 27  362   512   34
City3   90  150 145   274   56
```

After multiplication, I want new/replace dataframe with values :

```
        JAN     FEB MAR ....DEC
City1   192    1896 3036    1656
City2   7208   918  12308   8092
City3   504    280  8120    2464
```

I am able to do it by one column at a time with the code :

```
Df.select("JAN","CONSTANT").withColumn("JAN",col('JAN') * col ('CONSTANT')).show()
```

Is there any function/loop where i can get the entire column multiplication and new dataframe values all months?

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: Spark Version 2.4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could express your logic using a **`struct`** of **`structs`**. Structs are basically the same as a **`column in higher order`**, so we can assign **`them a name`**, **`multiply them by constant`**, and then select them using **`columnname.*`**. This way you dont have to do **`withColumn 12 times.`** You could put all your months in **`listofmonths`**.

```
df.show() #sampledata
#+-----+---+---+---+---+--------+
#| City|JAN|FEB|MAR|DEC|Constant|
#+-----+---+---+---+---+--------+
#|City1|160|158|253|391|      12|
#|City2|212| 27|362|512|      34|
#|City3| 90|150|145|274|      56|
#+-----+---+---+---+---+--------+



listofmonths=['JAN','FEB','MAR','DEC']

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("arr", F.struct(*[(F.col(x)*F.col('Constant')).alias(x) for x in listofmonths]))\
  .select("City","arr.*")\
  .show()

#+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
#| City| JAN| FEB|  MAR|  DEC|
#+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
#|City1|1920|1896| 3036| 4692|
#|City2|7208| 918|12308|17408|
#|City3|5040|8400| 8120|15344|
#+-----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

You could also just use **`df.columns`** instead of **`listofmonths`** like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("arr", F.struct(*[(F.col(x)*F.col('Constant')).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x!='City' and x!='Constant']))\
  .select("City","arr.*")\
  .show()
```